# Connecting 14/2 to wire with 30amp breaker behind it

Tags: electrical

My camera floodlight lost power and I haven’t been able to find any switches or breakers to give it power again. I went into the attic, confirmed the wire was dead for as much of it as I could trace so I ripped it out. I have some 14/2 that I can use to reach the light box, but the only hot wire I could find in my attic is a run of either 10/2 or 12/2. When I tried breakers to see what controlled it, a dual 30amp breaker marked Heater 1 Heater 2 was the one responsible.

Why do I only see 10/2 or 12/2 for this circuit? I thought a dual 30amp breaker would feed 10/3.

And is it safe to create a junction with this circuit so my 14/2 can power my floodlight cam? What are the risks of doing so?

Comment: Heaters usually do not use neutral so most times they mark(suppose to) the white as the second hot.  You cannot use 14/2 or 12/2 on the 30 amp breaker, unless the heater/s are not used anymore and you change the breaker for 15 amp.

Comment: Did you look for tripped GFCIs? May not be in a logical place, depending, but "switches and breakers" implies you didn't look for a tripped GFCI, which is definitely something you should do for a cable that "mysteriously" lost power, especially if it leads somewhere wet, like to an outdoor camera.

Comment: You "ripped out" a cable that had been working because it was dead. You might be beyond our ability to help if that's your decision making process. All you needed to do was find the fault (or GFCI) and fix (or reset) it.

Comment: Agreed, you have a pattern of bad ideas around electrical.  Learn your limits and avoid Dunning-Kruger.

Answer (score 3):

##### TL;DR NO!

While it isn't 100% definite, it looks like you've got a 30A 240V double-breaker connected to a 10 AWG 2-wire cable for heaters. That is typical. A standard electric heater does not need neutral, so a 2-wire cable works just fine. Where you see 3-wire cables for 240V appliances are things like:

- Ovens - for the lights and controls
- Clothes Dryers - for the light, motor and controls
- Some HVAC - for some motors and controls. But when HVAC has separate power for an outside compressor or for a large resistance heater, that part is often straight 240V with no neutral.

There are a bunch of reasons why you can't connect typical small stuff (15A, 20A receptacles and devices designed for hardwiring into a 15A or 20A circuit) to a 30A breaker. In addition most such small stuff is not compatible with 240V, only 120V. (Exceptions: a lot of computers and similar electronics designed for worldwide use, and some lighting.) But most importantly, you are *never* allowed to connect 12 AWG or 14 AWG wire to a 30A circuit, because the primary purpose of the breaker is to protect the wiring, and 30A requires 10 AWG (or larger capacity - smaller AWG is larger capacity) wire.

Comment: For completeness, the problem isn't just wire size. Extending a 30A circuit with 10AWG wire to a 15A or 20A receptacle for the camera would also be a code violation.